# How to handle multiple approval in purchasing controller in rails 3.1.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is a purchasing controller in our rails 3.1.0 app. A purchasing needs 4 approvals and we want to separate the approval from regular editing. What's the best way to handle this approval? One way is to add 4 custom routes in purchasing controller for approval. Is there a way to build another controller such as purchasing_approve for handling the approval? If it does, how to construct the view, controller and declaration in routes.rb?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the approval process just changes an attribute of the purchase model, I'd advise you to use a custom action in the purchase controller. Like [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/35-custom-rest-actions).

If the approval has it's own table and it's a more complex process, it makes sense to create another controller. The implementation though depends on how you want to show the process to the user.

If you describe the user experience you have in mind I could give you a more complete answer.

Comment: The approval only changes the attributes in purchasing model and does not have it own data.

Comment: So you should go with the custom rest action inside the purchase controller. That's the right way of doing it.

Comment: For customer rest action, is there a way to add a custom view for the custom action? There is approve or not approve option and we would like to allow user to choose between them. Also one approval is based upon other approvals. We would like to list them all when one is approving. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can create 2 rest actions, one "approve" as GET and another "save_approval" as POST. In the first one you would have a Purchase.find(id, :include => [:approvals]), for example. Then you would create a html page called approve.html.erb in the views/purchases folder to show them and the form the user would use to submit its approval to the save_approval action. It's a little messy to right it as a comment but I hope it helps.

Comment: How to link the form submitted and "save_approval" as POST? I guess it must be something done in :approvals view. Please feel free to use formal answer for this question. Is one custom action OK for both? Thanks.

Comment: <%= form_tag save_approval_purchase_path do %>